# After opening a web page with mechanize, how can I continue submit

Tags: python, web-crawler, html, mechanize

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('someurl.com')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['user'] = 'myname'
br.form['pw'] ='pw'
req=br.submit()
```

After submit, I logged on a new page, which further requires me to click a 'next'

```
<input type="submit" value="   Next   " name="B1"> <input type="reset" value="    Clear    " name="B2"></td>
```

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution is very easy, as once you have a browser instance, it just works like a real browser; in this problem, you could just submit again after the first successful submit.

So, here is the original code:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('someurl.com')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['user'] = 'myname'
br.form['pw'] ='pw'
req=br.submit()
```

Then repeat what you did to move on to next page (below is the complete solution):

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser() # now you are at first login page
br.open('someurl.com')
br.select_form(nr=0)    # select the form from the first login page
br.form['user'] = 'myname'
br.form['pw'] ='pw'
req=br.submit() # now you are at second login page
br.select_form(nr=0) # select the form from the second login page
br.form['user'] = 'myname'
br.form['pw'] ='pw'
req=br.submit()
```